# Getting Runtime Error 91 when using Cells.Find

Tags: excel, vba

I want to do the following:

I have assigned a date, which I have also declared as a Date type, to a variable by using:

```
var1 = Worksheets("Sheet1").Cells(rowCounter, 8).Value
```

The Date gets correctly assigned to var1 as `#01.08.2018 00:15:00#` in the Locals window.

Now I wanted to search for that Date value on a different worksheet and assign its location in 2 variables for row and column with these lines of code:

```
    Set timesearch = Worksheets("Sheet2").Cells.Find(What:=var1, LookIn:=xlFormulas, LookAt:=xlPart, SearchOrder:=xlByRows, SearchDirection:=xlNext, MatchCase:=False, SearchFormat:=False)
timeRow = Range(timesearch.Address).Row
timeCol = Range(timesearch.Address).Column
```

`timeRow` and `timeCol` are declared als `Long`.

The cells where the Values to be searched for on `Sheet2` are custom fomatted as `DD.MM.YYYY hh:mm`

When I debug using F8, it always throws error 91 at the `Set`Statement. What I find odd about this is, that this code has worked in the past on the same workbook, just now it started to throw an error.

Is there something I missed out on, or is there even a more elegant solution to do this?

Comment: That means that the `Find` was unsuccessful, so `timesearch` is `Nothing`... though to clarify, is it the `Set` line that throws the error, or `timeRow = Range(timesearch.Address).Row`?

Comment: I just checked and indeed, in the Locals window timesearch reads as Nothing.

Comment: Not related to your Q, but `Range(timesearch.Address).Row`  can be replaced  with `timesearch.Row`

Comment: I managed to solve the problem by reformatting all relevant cells as `DD.MM.YYYY hh:mm`. They might have been accidentally changed to different format that also includes seconds or something. Thanks to everyone, though.